# phoneGap 'weinre' debugger javascript error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, weinre

I'm having trouble on getting the 'weinre' debugger of phonegap to work.

Tried already with their [Hello world app](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world) and with my [very simple demo](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/469781/builds)

The result is the same. Whenever I try the debug page, I get these javascript errors on the debug page

[image]

In my demo, I also tried including this script

```
<script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#blackjim_myPhoneGapDemo"></script>
```

and then trying the `http://debug.build.phonegap.com/client/#blackjim_myPhoneGapDemo` page. The result is always the same.

Any idea on why I get these errors? Is it a known issue?